# Access token is returning null for Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app which is having facebook login, I have used Facebook SDK for facebook login in app, Everything is ok but after login when I try to fetch the details from Graph API it returns a null value in AccessToken.

I already mentioned the facebook app id and facebook activity in manifest file. How to fetch access token for facebook anyone can suggest me, it will be great help for me.

I am using this code for fetching data:

```
public void RequestData(){
    System.out.println("Request data method ");

    final AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    System.out.println("access token = "+accessToken);

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

            JSONObject jsonn = response.getJSONObject();
            try {
                if(jsonn != null){

                    String text = jsonn.getString("name")+
                            jsonn.getString("email")+
                            jsonn.getString("id")+
                            jsonn.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

                    FpersonName = jsonn.getString("name");
                    FpersonEmail = jsonn.getString("email");
                    FpersonPhotoUrl = jsonn.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                    FpersonSocialId = jsonn.getString("id");
                    System.out.println("fb details = "+text);


                    if(FpersonName != null && FpersonEmail != null && FpersonPhotoUrl != null && FpersonSocialId != null){
                        loginFromFb = true;
                        new LoginGoogleAsyncTask().execute();
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

And I have also defined SDK in `oncreate()` method and CallBack in `onActivityResult`.

This is the error for access token:  `"D/GraphRequest: Warning: Request without access token missing application ID or client token."`

Comment: Did u add your APP id in manifest file?

Comment: yes  i already add app id..

Answer (score 1):

Include a profile tracker in your code. It's onCurrentProfileChanged() will get triggered when there is a change in profile ( Initially, your profile would be null, after login it gets changed to user profile upon which access token would be available )

```
mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
@Override
protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
// Include your method in here
requestData();
}
};
```

Do not forget to stop tracking in onDestroy()

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private boolean isResumed = false;
accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                                                       AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                if (isResumed) {
                    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
                    } else {
                        // currentaccestoken has your accesstoken value
                    }
                }
            }
        };

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }
```